# Статистика по входу на сайт

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net

Нужна помощь. Не знаю как сделать статистику кто заходит на сайт(желательно IP), какие страницы чаше открываются, отчёт должен разделятся по месяцам и желательно что бы он отображался на html. Нашел похожею статью https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568497/asp-net-visitors-counter
но не могу понять откуда там взялся `lblCounter` может там и написано но мой английский плоховат. Прошу вашей помощи!

В общем вот что получилось:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.countMe();

    DataSet tmpDs = new DataSet();
    tmpDs.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/base.xml"));

    Label1.Text = tmpDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["hits"].ToString();
    Label2.Text = tmpDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["IP"].ToString();
}
private void countMe()
{
    DataSet tmpDs = new DataSet();
    tmpDs.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/base.xml"));

    int hits = Int32.Parse(tmpDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["hits"].ToString());
    string ip = Request.UserHostAddress;

    hits += 1;

    tmpDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["hits"] = hits.ToString();
    tmpDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["IP"] = ip.ToString();

    tmpDs.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/base.xml"));

}
```

Но IP перезаписывается как это устранить?
Попробовал написать так

```
tmpDs.Tables[0].Rows[tmpDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count]["IP"] = ip;
```

Не помогло

Comment: Ну, там только код, разметки нет. lblCounter - некий контрол на странице (судя по префиксу lbl - скорее всего asp:Label)

Comment: Да поменял на Label заработало вот ещё бы он умел писать IP с которых заходили

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод, который вы приводите, очень плох. Во-первых, каждый раз при открытии страницы будет будет происходить чтение, запись, сериализация и десеализация xml файла. Во-вторых, подобный код вызова нужно будет писать на каждой странице. В-третьих, в какой-то момент вы наткнетесь на проблему параллельного доступа к xml файлу из разных потоков при одновременном входе нескольких человек на сайт.

Можно рассмотреть следующие подходы для сбора статистики.

**Вариант 1.**

Для обработки запросов переопределить поведение `Application_BeginRequest` в `Global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
    //... запись в хранилище статистики
}
```

Описание доступных свойств объекта `request` типа `HttpRequest` можно посмотреть [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.httprequest(v=vs.110).aspx).

**ИЛИ**

В том же ASP.NET можно сделать на основе `HttpModule`. Модуль будет так же получать все запросы к серверу. Подробнее можно посмотреть [эту статью](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms227673.aspx).

**Вариант 2.**

Написать `Javascript` код, который будет подгружаться на всех страничках и отправлять `GET` запрос на страницу сбора статистики. Такую страницу удобнее всего писать как [HttpHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms228090.aspx), но подойдет и любая `aspx` страничка. Сохраняем полученные данные в хранилище.

**Вариант 3.**

Можно включить на веб-сервере (например, `IIS`) логирование. В логи пишется информация об ip-адресе отправителя, запрашиваемой странице и тд. Затем эти логи можно вычитывать и обрабатывать (записывать в хранилище, обрабатывать, отображать в отчетах...).

По умолчанию `IIS` хранит логи в каталоге: `c:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles`.

Пример записи в логе:

```
2002-05-02 17:42:15 172.22.255.255 - 172.30.255.255 80 GET /images/picture.jpg - 200 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;MSIE+5.5;+Windows+2000+Server)
```

Описание формата выглядит так:

```
#date time c-ip cs-username s-ip s-port cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query sc-status cs(User-Agent)
```

Здесь:

- `date` и `time` - дата и время записи,
- `c-ip` - адрес клиента,
- `cs-uri-stem` - имя страницы.
- `cs-uri-query` - строка запроса

Прочитать логи можно так:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines("data.log");
foreach(var line in lines)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) || line.StartsWith("#"))
        continue;

    var cells = line.Split(' ');

    var date = cells[0];
    var time = cells[1];
    var cip = cells[2];
    var uristem = cells[7];
    var uriquery = cells[8];

    // обработать полученный данные
}
```

**Вариант 4.**

Поставить на сайт один из бесплатных готовых продуктов [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) или [Yandex Metrica](https://metrika.yandex.ru/), которые часто используются для подобных целей.

**Хранилище**

Варианты 1, 2 и 3 предполагают использование хранилища для собранной статистики. Им может быть любая **база данных** (`SQL`, `NOSQL`) или простое Key-Value хранилище. Если будет использоваться **файл**, то запить в него лучше сделать асинхронно по таймеру из одного потока. Так же нужно избежать операций открытия и закрытия файла при каждом запросе страниц пользователями. Данные можно хранить просто **в памяти**, если это допускается задачей.

Comment: 4 вариант отпадает, так как сайт будет находится внутри корпоративной сети.

Comment: 3 вариант не подходит, так как не все умеют читать логи. У меня в планах веб страница с отчётом, где можно будет выбрать дату и время, и он отобразит отчёт за этот промежуток. Или подскажите как можно вытащить такую информацию из из лог файла.

Comment: @Павел добавил пример для варианта 3

Comment: а можно объяснить откуда StartWith взялась и за что оно отвечает?

Comment: @Павел строчки не содержащие саму информацию о заходах начинаются с `#`

Comment: у меня ругается на него говорит что string не содержит определения для "StartWith"  вот я и спросил что он делает

Comment: @Павел Ошибся. Метод называется StartsWith - https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/baketfxw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: есть проблема. Лог файл записывается каждый день с новым названием а точнее с датой пример(u_ex150925.log u_ex150928.log) то есть год месяц день. И как заставить его с читывать  нужный файл в нужное время?

Comment: @Павел А как вам нужно считывать? Если знаете дату, то можно брать файл по этой дате...

Comment: всё нашёл, на самом IIS можно выставить как делить отчёт на день месяц или год.

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Буду отталкиваться от вашего решения.